# Add child-site to path of parent site in Nginx

Tags: nginx

In the interests of keeping my codebase modular, I have two static websites - `site_a`, which is the parent site, and `site_b`, which may be considered a child site. I am trying to find the right way to append `site_b` to a path of `site_a`, such that `site_a/path` is equivalent to the `site_b`'s `/` directory.

Note that each site instance has its own set of static resources (img, css, js), and should be referenced from the corresponding web directory on the server, and there may be some overlap in the names of some of the resources (eg. style.css) and folders (eg. /img/..).

Any pointers of help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching is a proxy_pass (Or I think it would work in your case).

site_a configuration:

```
location = /path {
    return 301 /path/;
}
location = /path/ {
    proxy_pass http://site_b/;
}
```

This should work if you only want it to be exactly like this, be careful, because the /path part is changed by / , but if you need the rest of the url, you could do:

```
location = /path {
    return 301 /path/;
}

location  /path/ {
    proxy_pass http://site_b/;
}
```

Like this, site_a/path/pathtoglory/ would show site_b/pathtoglory/.

Choose whichever you like the most (or fits your actual situation).

Any more info on proxy_pass for special configurations can be found here:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/